# C# mongodb driver 2.0, how to make ToListAsync() to return List<Entity>?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to using the `mongodb` new `c#` driver, which is version `2.x`.
I want to retrieve all the `Entity` object as a `List<Entity>`, however, `ToListAsync` seems only return `List<BsonDocument>`,

```
var collection = _db.GetCollection<Entity>("EntityTable");  
var ret = await collection.Find("{}").Project(Builders<Enity>.Projection.Exclude("_id")).ToListAsync();
```

How can I get `List<Entity>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `As<TResult>()` method (it's a part of the `MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluent<TDocument, TProjection>` interface).

Here's your code, updated to use this method:

```
var ret = await collection
    .Find("{}")
    .Project(Builders<Entity>.Projection.Exclude("_id"))
    .As<Entity>()
    .ToListAsync();
```

You might need to add the `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` attribute to your `Entity` class in order to make this work.

Comment: Is that possible for my `Entity` do not contain a field named `_id`?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then I believe it should be possible, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes @Donut, you can use like this too

```
    var ret = await collection
.Find("{}")
.Project<Entity>(Builders<Entity>.Projection.Exclude("_id"))
.ToListAsync();
```